# How can I work with the DOM container immediately after updating an observableArray in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've been using Knockout for a few days now and this is what I've come up with to organize my view models and javascript models:

```
//******************************************************************************
// jQUERY START:
//******************************************************************************
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var panel1 = $('#panel1>section');
    var panel2 = $('#panel2>section');

    $('#loader').ajaxStart(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }).ajaxComplete(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(panel1));
});

//******************************************************************************
// VIEW MODEL:
//******************************************************************************
function ViewModel(_panel1)
{
    var self      = this;
    this.vmHeader = new HeaderViewModel();
    this.vmPanel1 = new Panel1ViewModel(_panel1);
}

//******************************************************************************
// Panel1ViewModel:
//******************************************************************************
function Panel1ViewModel(_element)
{
    var self            = this;
    self.element        = _element;
    self.filters        = ['Operations', 'Jobs', 'Shifts', 'Hours'];
    self.selectedFilter = ko.observable();
    self.vmOperations   = new OperationsViewModel();
    self.vmJobs         = new JobsViewModel();
    self.vmShifts       = new ShiftsViewModel();
    self.vmHours        = new HoursViewModel();

    //PUBLIC METHODS:
    self.clickFilter = function(filter)
    {
        self.selectedFilter(filter);

        switch(filter)
        {
            case 'Operations':
                self.vmOperations.load(self.clear, self.element);
                break;

            case 'Jobs':
                self.vmJobs.load(self.clear, self.element);
                break;

            case 'Shifts':
                self.vmShifts.load(self.clear, self.element);
                break;

            case 'Hours':
                self.vmHours.load(self.clear, self.element);
                break;
        }
    }

    self.clear = function()
    {
        //test each view model to see if it currently has items loaded and empty them.
        if (self.vmOperations.operations() != null) { self.vmOperations.operations(null); }
        if (self.vmJobs.jobs() != null) { self.vmJobs.jobs(null); }
        if (self.vmShifts.shifts() != null) { self.vmShifts.shifts(null); }
        if (self.vmHours.hours() != null) { self.vmHours.hours(null); }
    };
}

//******************************************************************************
// ShiftsViewModel:
//******************************************************************************
function ShiftsViewModel()
{
    var self      = this;
    self.shifts   = ko.observableArray(null);
    self.selected = ko.observable();

    //PUBLIC METHODS:
    self.load = function (callback, element)
    {
        var options = {
            url:    '/api/shifts',
            type:   'GET',
            data: {
                operationID: 1
            }
        };

        async_load(options, function (data)
        {
            callback();

            self.shifts(
                $.map(data.Items, function (item, index)
                {
                    return new Shift(item);
                })
            );

            element.overscroll();  <--- PROBLEM IS HERE!
        });
    }

    self.click = function(shift)
    {
        self.selected(shift.id);
    };
}

//******************************************************************************
// SHIFT MODEL:
//******************************************************************************
function Shift(data)
{
    var self       = this;
    this.operation = data.Operation;
    this.shopOrder = data.ShopOrder;
    this.date      = data.Date;
    this.id        = data.ID;
    this.number    = data.Number;
    this.start     = ko.observable(data.Start);
    this.end       = ko.observable(data.End);
    this.isRunning = ko.observable(data.IsRunning);

    //computed properties.
    this.shiftDate = ko.computed(function()
    {
        var date = (this.end() == '') ? new Date() : new Date(this.end());

        return date.toLocaleDateString();
    }, this);

    this.startTime = ko.computed(function()
    {
        return (new Date(this.start())).toLocaleTimeString();
    }, this);

    this.endTime = ko.computed(function()
    {
        var time = '---';

        if (this.isRunning() == 'False')
        {
            time = (new Date(this.end())).toLocaleTimeString();
        }

        return time;
    }, this);
}

//******************************************************************************
// GLOBAL FUNCTIONS:
//******************************************************************************
function async_load(options, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:            options.url,
        async:          true,
        cache:          false,
        type:           options.type,
        data:           options.data,
        dataType:       'json',
        contentType:    'application/json',
        success:    callback,
        error: function (request, type, errorThrown)
        {
            error_handler(options.url, request, type, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function sync_load(options)
{
    var error = false;
    var data = $.ajax({
        url:            options.url,
        async:          false,
        cache:          false,
        type:           options.type,
        data:           options.data,
        dataType:       'json',
        contentType:    'application/json',
        error: function (request, type, errorThrown)
        {
            error = true;
            error_handler(options.url, request, type, errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;

    if (!error)
    {
        data = eval('(' + data + ')');
    }

    return (error) ? null : data;
}

function error_handler(name, request, type, errorThrown)
{
    switch (request.status)
    {
        case 404:
            alert('The ' + name + ' could not be found.');
            break;

        case 500:
            alert('There was an internal server error loading ' + name + '.');
            //redirect the user to a page with further instructions.
            break;

        default:
            alert('An error occurred: (' + request.status + ' ' + request.statusText + ').');
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
        <section id="panel1" data-bind="with: vmPanel1">
            <nav data-bind="foreach: filters">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, css: { selected: $data == $root.vmPanel1.selectedFilter() }, click: $root.vmPanel1.clickFilter"></a>
            </nav>
            <section>
                <section id="panel1Data">
                <!-- ko foreach: vmOperations.operations -->
                    <article class="operation" data-bind="css: { selected: $data.operationID == $root.vmPanel1.vmOperations.selected() }, click: $root.vmPanel1.vmOperations.click">
                        <div class="name" data-bind="text: name"></div>
                        <div class="number" data-bind="text: number"></div>
                        <div class="sequence" data-bind="text: sequence"></div>
                    </article>                            
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko foreach: vmJobs.jobs -->
                    <article data-bind="pageBreak: operation, label: 'operation', level: 1"></article>
                    <article class="job" data-bind="css: { selected: $data.jobID == $root.vmPanel1.vmJobs.selected() }, click: $root.vmPanel1.vmJobs.click">
                        <div class="start date">
                            <label data-bind="text: startMonth"></label>
                            <div data-bind="text: startDay"></div>
                            <span data-bind="text: startTime"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="end date">
                            <label data-bind="text: endMonth"></label>
                            <div data-bind="text: endDay"></div>
                            <span data-bind="text: endTime"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="shoporder" data-bind="text: shopOrder"></div>
                        <div class="toolconfig" data-bind="toolConfig: $data"></div>
                        <div class="lot" data-bind="text: lot"></div>
                    </article>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko foreach: vmShifts.shifts -->
                    <article data-bind="pageBreak: operation, label: 'operation', level: 1"></article>
                    <article data-bind="pageBreak: shopOrder, label: 'job', level: 2"></article>
                    <article data-bind="pageBreak: shiftDate(), level: 3"></article>
                    <article class="shift" data-bind="css: { selected: $data.id == $root.vmPanel1.vmShifts.selected() }, click: $root.vmPanel1.vmShifts.click">
                        <div class="shift" data-bind="text: number"></div>
                        <div class="start time" data-bind="text: startTime()"></div>
                        <div class="end time" data-bind="text: endTime()"></div>
                    </article>
                <!-- /ko -->
```

Depending on the filter that is selected, the appropriate list of data (operations, jobs, shifts, or hours) will be loaded into panel 1 and the jQuery Overscroll plugin is used to create an IPad scrolling effect.

The problem is in the ShiftsViewModel on the line where the Overscroll plugin is being called. When debugging, I noticed that the plugin isn't doing anything because the container element has no width/height.  When running the program, the container is updated with the correct data, so it looks like the call to overscroll is running before the data is written to the DOM container by Knockout.

Since the overscroll call is inside the ajax callback which runs after data is received, I thought it would be OK. Is Knockout asynchronously updating the DOM?  I'm not sure where to go from here... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

In the jQuery ready function, I was caching the DOM element before any data was loaded and then using that cached element which didn't have anything inside the container element.

So, I changed this:

```
var panel1 = $('#panel1>section');
```

to:

```
var panel1 = '#panel1>section';
```

And then in the ShiftsViewModel, I changed this line:

```
element.overscroll();
```

to:

```
$(element).overscroll();
```

and it appears to be working now...